# Pasar de un Form a otro Ayuda

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Tengo un dos proyectos juntos en la misma solución
agregue un botón a form1.cs para que al seleccionarlo se abra form2.cs (que esta en otro proyecto)

proyecto1

```
 form1.cs
```

proyecto2

```
 form2.cs
```

Comment: ¿Por qué lo tienes en otro proyecto? Es decir, es posible abrirlo, pero también podrías tenerlo en el mismo proyecto y sería más práctico mostrarlo. Dicho esto, un formulario puede pertenecer a tantos proyectos como haga falta. Obviamente, tendrá que programarse de manera que funcione en todos y cada uno de ellos, cosa que no es demasiado complicada.

Comment: Porqué en un proyecto hice los registros, inicios de sesión y el otro  proyecto contiene un mapa
¿Puedes ayudarme con eso?

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y ganar tu primera medalla.  Sobre el grito final de _ayudaaaaa_, probablemente no sea bienvenido aquí, de hecho [te podrían votar negativamente por pedir ayuda urgente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152), sugiero no incluirlo.

Comment: cambiaré mi pregunta a ¿hay alguna razón para que no estén en el mismo proyecto? Sobre todo si uno es inicio de sesión y el otro es la aplicación en si, me parece, de entrada, que debieran ser un solo proyecto y no dos.

Comment: la razón por la que están separados es porque uno lo hice yo y otro mi compañero, pensábamos hacer el mapa de prueba pero al final estuvieron separados

Comment: Eso no impide que ahora, que ya los tienes, los pongas en el mismo proyecto. Es decir, no es razón suficiente para mantenerlos separados.

Comment: estoy preguntando algo y no respondes mi duda.

Answer (score 1):

Cada aplicación, sean o no parte de la misma solución, controla su propio espacio de memoria y los sistemas operativos modernos, como Windows, no permiten que un aplicación haga mayor cosa en el espacio de otra (con excepciones).

Para ser formales, diría entonces que **no puedes, *directamente*, mostrar un formulario que está en otra aplicación**, a menos que esta aplicación lo permita de alguna forma.

Dicho esto, si puedes *solicitar* o *dirigir* a una aplicación externa a realizar alguna acción. Esto independientemente de que la otra aplicación la hayas hecho tu, venga con el sistema o sea de un tercero.

Dado que no brindas información suficiente en tu pregunta, comenzare asumiendo que el formulario que te interesa *mostrar* es el formulario principal de la otra aplicación. Esta es la manera más sencilla de hacerlo, pues *mostrar* el formulario, consiste básicamente en *lanzar* la otra aplicación, lo que hacemos a través del sistema operativo.

Así, si estamos en `Programa1.exe` y queremos lanzar `Programa2.exe`, podemos valernos de la clase [`Process`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netcore-3.1)

```
Process programa2 = new Process();
programa2.StartInfo.FileName = "programa2.exe";
programa2.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
programa2.Start();
programa2.WaitForExit();
```

Acá, estoy asumiendo que el ejecutable de `programa2` se encuentra en la ruta actual de `programa1`. Si no fuera el caso, puedes colocar una ruta absoluta o relativa, para lanzarlo, por ejemplo:

```
programa2.StartInfo.FileName = "c:\\program files\\mi compañía\\programa2.exe";
```

o bien

```
programa2.StartInfo.FileName = "..\\auxiliares\\programa2.exe";
```

Dado que estoy incluyendo una llamada al método `WaitForExit()`, `programa1` no responderá hasta que termine la ejecución de `programa2.exe`, pero puedes obviarla y ambas aplicaciones funcionarán de manera independiente, que quizás es lo que tu usuario espera.

Ahora, suponiendo que el formulario de marras no es el formulario principal de `programa2.exe`, una forma estándar de *solicitar* algo a una aplicación, es pasarle algún dato en la línea de comandos al invocarlo. En Windows lo típico sería usar la notación `/xxx`, aunque no tienes por que seguir esta convención:

```
c:\>programa2.exe /mostrarform2
```

cualquier cosa que pases al ejecutable como parámetro, llegará al método principal en forma de [argumentos de la función](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/), de tal manera que puedes comprobar y realizar la acción correspondiente en la programación de dicho método, por ejemplo:

```
static int Main(string[] args)
{
    initApp();
    //llegado el momento, validar si se recibió el parámetro para mostrar el formulario
    if (args.Length > 0 && args[0].Equals("/mostrarform2") {
      mostrarForm2();
    }
}
```

Para pasar el argumento al programa, utilizas la propiedad `Arguments` de `Process` antes de iniciarlo:

```
programa2.StartInfo.Arguments = "/mostrarform2";
programa2.Start();
```

Si sigues esta ruta y quieres ser más formal, puedes [analizar la línea de comandos con `System.CommandLine`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/march/net-parse-the-command-line-with-system-commandline)

Si `programa2` está corriendo, puedes utilizar comunicación inter-procesos para darle comandos o instrucciones desde `programa1`, pero no cubriré esos tópicos, porque esta respuesta es ya bastante larga.

Mencionaré, si te interesa el tema, que puedes hacerlo vía *named pipes*, vía TCP, utilizando automatización COM, entre otros.

Comment: ES una gran respuesta que no da una solucion mas trivial al problema que seria transformar el segundo proyecto a una dll y problema solucionado ;)

Comment: @gbianchi, llevas mucha razón! :)